# Parse.com CloudCode deploy failing - requested resource was not found

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using [Parse.com CloudCode](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code) to create some custom functionality for an iOS app.

To deploy a CloudCode app you use:

`terminal% parse deploy`

Everything was working fine and I was able to upload my cloud code to the backend but suddenly it stopped working and I absolutely don't know why. I am getting this response:

```
requested resource was not found
```

**EDIT:** 
The `main.js` is there, that is the file that has the changes. I tried to delete and recreate the app. The config is also correct. I restarted my computer, reset the connection, but still getting that response. Here is the full Terminal response after running `% parse deploy`:

```
% parse deploy
Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/path/to/main.js
Deploy failed. Retrying deploy...

Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/path/to/main.js
Deploy failed. Retrying deploy...

Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/path/to/main.js
Deploy failed. Retrying deploy...

Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/path/to/main.js
Deploy failed. Retrying deploy...

Uploading source files
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/path/to/main.js
requested resource was not found
```

Did anybody have the same or similar problem? If yes, what steps helped to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same happens for me too..

Comment: Me too - using parse cli version: 2.1.1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Parse.com customer service issue. See their website: https://status.parse.com/incidents/m0bl3rn1p4pm

Comment: If you need to deploy now, I figured it out.

Download [Parse CLI 2.1.0](https://parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/cli/parse-osx/2.1.0)

 Then run `chmod 777 ~/Downloads/parse-osx-2.1.0`

Then edit your host file: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

Add `127.0.0.1 parse.com` to the host file, ^O, then ^X

Navigate to your project directory, and run `~/Downloads/parse-osx-2.1.0 deploy`
Now remove parse.com from your host file.

The reason for the host file thing is that the Parse CLI auto updates it self on every command, and this prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

The newly released update has fixed this problem for me. You can either update using `parse udpate` or use curl `curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash`

Comment: Nope. This does not fix the issue on my mac.

Comment: I'm using the latest version cli version: 2.1.1??

Comment: @Taylorsuk, that's the version with the issue. Updating to that version _causes_ the problem.

Comment: Didn't have any choice in updating - bloody thing did it automatically! Oh well - will have to wait... daft thing is I only change cloud code every couple of months and today is that day!! Pffff!!

Answer (score 0):

I´m using it on JavaScript and just spamming "parse deploy" till the main.js is update do the work.

Is not nice, but it works :)